# Is that possible to have 3 applications running and intercommunicating together in the same port?

Tags: java, angular, spring, cross-domain

I have 2 backends api, one for authentication and the other for persisting in db, and one front end web gui. all of those are using cross origin, the 2 back end are in java spring and the front will be in angular 8, I'll use the cors too... Is that possible to run? there is a limit of application running at the same url  and port?

Comment: You cant have multiple apps on the same port. You can set up an apache/nginx reverse proxy in front and then redirect to your specific apps based on the path.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can not run multiple applications with the same URL and port. 
You have to separate all applications using port through which the server can identify the unique URL.
I don't how to change the port number for java but in angular, it should be changed as below.

```
ng serve --port <port number>
```

Thanks :)